# Right way to use the @NonNull annotation in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, annotations, non-nullable

I'd like to use the `@NonNull` annotation in Android, but I can't figure out just the right way to do it.
I propose you this example:

```
public void doStuff(@NonNull String s){
     //do work with s...    
}
```

So when i call `doStuff(null)` the IDE will give me a warning. The problem is that I cannot rely on this annotation since, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13484202/use-nullable-and-nonnull-java-annotations-more-effectivly) question points out, they don't propagate very far. So I'd like to put a null check on my method, like this:

```
 if(s==null) throw new IllegalAgrumentException();
```

But the IDE, assuming that `s!=null`, will warn me that `s==null` is always false. I'd like to know what is the best way to do this.

I personally think that there should be an annotation like `@ShouldntBeNull` that *only* checks and warns that null isn't passed to it, but *doesn't* complains when the value is null checked.

Comment: "I'd like to know what is the best way to do this" -- there should be a quick-fix in the IDE to suppress that warning. "I personally think..." -- you can [file a feature request](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list), if you like.

Comment: @CommonsWare There doesn't seem to be a quick `SuppressWarning` fix in Android Studio 1.3.2

Comment: Well, that stinks. :-(

Comment: Anyway I did as you suggested and filed a feature request. You can find it [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=186912)

Answer (score 13):

You can use [Objects.requireNonNull](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull(T)) for that. It will do the check internally (so the IDE will not show a warning on your function) and raise a [NullPointerException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html) when the parameter is `null`:

```
public MyMethod(@NonNull Context pContext) {
    Objects.requireNonNull(pContext);
    ...
}
```

If you want to throw another exception or use API level < 19, then you can just make your own helper-class to implement the same check. e.g.

```
public class Check {
    public static <T> T requireNonNull(T obj) {
        if (obj == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        return obj;
    }
}
```

and use it like so:

```
public MyMethod(@NonNull Context pContext) {
    Check.requireNonNull(pContext);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 8):

[Google examples](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture) do it as follows

```
import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull;

...

public void doStuff(@NonNull String sParm){
     this.sParm= checkNotNull(s, "sParm cannot be null!");
}
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use the comment-style suppression to disable that specific null check warning, e.g.:

```
    public MyMethod(@NonNull Context pContext) {
        //noinspection ConstantConditions
        if (pContext == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        ...
    }
```

You'll need that `//noinspection ConstantConditions` every time you do it.