# Making sense of non-null and nullability annotations

Tags: java, android, design-patterns, annotations, design-by-contract

I am not clear about how we properly use the annotation about nullable i.e. NonNull and Nullable.
I am not really comfortable with something like the following:

```
public void foo(@NonNull ArrayList<CustomObject> list) {  
   CustomObject o = list.get(0);  //etc
}
```

1) Is it non-sense to declare non-null **and** code defensively?
2) What is the most effective way to use such annotations? E.g. as an example
     -  how should they be used when using the builder pattern or
-  when defining an interface for concrete classes to implement? Should the method of implementing classes also contain the annotation or is it assumed?
3) In the snippet above is there a way to define non-null **and** non-empty?

Comment: I usually use `@NonNull` when I know a variable is guaranteed not to be null. As far as I'm aware it makes no difference to the compiled code, but suppresses all "might be `null`" warnings in the IDE. Conversely I use `@Nullable` where there are occasions where I *want* a variable to be null.

Comment: @MichaelDodd:Isn't that for your own self-documenting purposes when reviewing your code? What about a method that *other* devs will use/access e.g. a utility method or a method meant to be part of a module or library?

Comment: I suppose documentation and readability is the whole purpose of `android-annotations`. In my team at work we extensively use those annotations to clarify that a variable may/should never be `null`. Likewise, if library method a is annotated as such, it becomes advice as to whether or not a `null` check is required.

Comment: @MichaelDodd: Yes and what is the expected behavior? Declare a variable that should never be null and then access it without checking for null? Or check for null and throw an explicit NPE? Or check for null and stop processing and return some error value?

Comment: It all depends on your enviornment. In fact, [Kotlin's support of `@NonNull`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html#nullability-annotations) allows occurnaces of compile time errors when attempting to use `null`. In some enviornments, `@NonNull` could be teaching the defensive coding styles.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4963300

Answer (score 0):

Now I've had proper time to investigate, this is what I've found.

1)

It makes perfect sense to still code defensively while using the `@NonNull` annotation. Just because a parameter has a `@NonNull` annotation, `null` can still be passed at runtime. For example, with a data class like:

```
class DataClass {
    @NonNull private String notNullString;

    public DataClass() { notNullString = null; }

    public String toString() { return notNullString; }
}
```

The [IDE will warn](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPLML.png) that you're assigning `null` to a `@NonNull` variable, but calling `toString()` **will** return `null`. To get around this, and IDE warnings asking [why you're null-checking a `@NonNull` variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32652402/right-way-to-use-the-nonnull-annotation-in-android-studio), Google tends to use [`PreConditions.checkNotNull(T)`](http://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot/api/docs/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html#checkNotNull-T-java.lang.Object-) - see [example code](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture/blob/todo-mvp/todoapp/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/architecture/blueprints/todoapp/data/source/TasksRepository.java).

2)

As mentioned in the comments, personally I use the annotations as guidance as to whether `null` is an expected value or not. I can't find any solid examples of this being used within a builder pattern, but potentially you can enforce this by using `checkNotNull()` in your `build()` method so that any unexpected `null` values throw a `NullPointerException`.

As for the concrete class, it's up to you but personally I would add them for consistency.

3)

Given the above, I'd do it this way:

```
public void foo(@NonNull ArrayList<CustomObject> list) {
    checkNotNull(list, "List is null!");
    if (!list.isEmpty()) {  
        CustomObject o = list.get(0);  //etc
    }
}
```

Comment: In my mind I was expecting that the purpose of the annotation would be to promote a design by contract there by reducing the myriads of check for null leading to slightly more optimized (less ifs) and cleaner code. If we are expected to check for null anyway then it seems that the reasoning is too complex. I understand that it helps in documenting things but it all depends in the end how one thinks of what @NonNull. Do I make sense?

Comment: Yeah that makes sense. In an ideal world there should be an accompanying `annotationProcessor` that ensures that anything marked `@NonNull` is never assigned `null`. However, it would also need to check that the same variable is always assigned with a default value, else [uninitialized objects](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16699593/uninitialized-object-vs-object-initialized-to-null) will become a problem. That would introduce a new set of problems.