# Conflict with constructor. There is no IAE while in constructor it is

Tags: java, exception

This is my constructor. And i have this conflict(. I must check input argument in set method?

```
public Car(int maxSpeed, String manufacturer, String model, String carType) {
    super(maxSpeed, manufacturer, model);
    if (carType == null || carType.isEmpty()) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    this.carType = carType;
}


public void setCarType(String carType) {

    this.carType = carType;
}
```

Comment: Well yes - if it's not valid in the constructor, why would you expect it to be valid when calling the setter later?

Comment: do you have `import java.lang.IllegalArgumentException;` ?

Comment: I dont have import java.lang.IllegalArgumentException;

Comment: If you have a compile time error saying that there is not this Exception, you need to add this import line at the beggining of you class file.  Or change the throw for `throw new java.lang.IllegalArgumentException();`

Comment: It not a good idea to throw exceptions in constructors.  It is best to put the throw in the `setCarType()`

Comment: Ok) What you think about set method? Am I must to add check input parameter?

Comment: Or i am must delete set method?

Comment: @JoseLuis - He >>does not<< need to import it.  `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException` is in `java.lang`.  It will be imported on demand.

Comment: @stephen-c I undertood that he can't compile because there was not this exception class, that's because I said to add the import.

Comment: @myrat-arazgeldiev You need that `carType` never gets null values.  This question could help to you:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2997768/java-constructor-style-check-parameters-arent-null

Comment: And your documentation has to say that this parameter don't accept null values.

Comment: @myrat-arazgeldiev In this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6086334/is-it-good-practice-to-make-the-constructor-throw-an-exception the first answer by Stephen C says that yes, it's correct to throw this exception.